# Add only objects that don't currently exist to Realm database

Tags: ios, database, swift, nspredicate, realm

I have a subjects Realm database:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Subjects: Object {

dynamic var subject = "" 

override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "subject"
  }

}
```

In the database I have four subjects, say, Computing 101, English, History and Geography. Now, I have a struct that can hold an array of subjects, like so:

```
struct mySubjects {

static var subjects:Array<String>  = [String]()

 }
```

The user can add subjects to the struct, say, Computing 101, English, History, Geography and Accountancy for Engineers.

My problem is that I only want to add the one subject that does not already exist in the database, i.e. "Accountancy for Engineers". I thought I could simply code a NSPredicate like so:

```
 for subject in mySubjects.subjects  {

    let myPredicate:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "subject != '\(subject)'")
    results = realm.objects(Subjects).filter(myPredicate)
```

No luck :(. Any suggestions?

Comment: So, just to clarify, you have the Subjects in the Realm database, but you also have a struct that can hold an array of Subjects....?

Comment: Yes. I use the struct to hold the information until I the user decides to save the information to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you've set up a primary key, you could use the [`objectForPrimaryKey(_:key:)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm19objectForPrimaryKeyuRdq_CS_6Object_FS0_FTMq_3keyPSs9AnyObject__GSqq__) function.

If the result of something like `realm.objectForPrimaryKey(Subject.self, "Subject Name")` is nil, then that subject doesn't exist in the database yet.